# What is the form of the binomial theorem in a general ring? I mean what's the expression for $(a+b)^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, binomial-theorem

What is the form of the binomial theorem in a general ring?
I mean what's the expression for $(a+b)^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer

Comment: If the ring is commutative, then the same as what you know for "numbers".

Comment: Continuing what Peter was saying, given a ring (assumed to be unital), there is a notion of '$1$', so there is a notion of $n=1+\cdots+1$ with the sum containing $n$ ones.  Some of these might be zero (such as the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$).  Regardless, the statement still makes sense in the context of any ring.

Comment: so what is the formula I'm confused :(

Comment: It's the same formula.

Comment: even when the ring is non commutative?

Comment: @Elliott Take a look at my answer here, which exlpains how to view a non-commutative version of the binomial theorem.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156958/how-to-visualize-binomial-theorem-geometrically/156968#156968

Answer (score 9):

It's the usual formula $\sum \left(\begin{matrix} n\\ k\end{matrix}\right) a^k b^{n-k}$, if the ring is commutative. Terms of the form $\left(\begin{matrix} n\\ k\end{matrix}\right)$ are interpreted in a general ring $A$ via the unique homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to A$.

In a noncommutative ring the formula is harder to write down concisely: for $n=2$ we have $a^2+ab+ba+b^2$, for $n=3, a^3+a^2b+aba+ba^2+b^2a+bab+ab^2+b^3$, and indeed in general we now have $2^n$ terms instead of just $n+1$. So the "formula" is just that $(a+b)^n$ is the sum of all words in $a$ and $b$ of length $n$, which isn't much help to anybody-though you do need to worry about such expressions, for instance, in matrix calculus. In this case the fact that the $b$s can't all be moved to one side explains the difference of the Frechet derivative from the one you learn in ordinary calculus.

Answer (score 3):

The usual formula is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n{\binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k}}$$
In a general commutative ring with identity it is the same, except you interpret $\binom{n}{k}$ as the element $1+1+1+\cdots+1$, where there are $\binom{n}{k}$ terms.